# Cisco Catalyst QoS queuing model

Tags: cisco-catalyst, qos

How Cisco Hardware queuing model (like 1p7q4t for Cat6800) are related to traffic classes (class-map) ? How assign the X traffic class to Y hardware queue ? Also, if only 6 classes are configured, does it mean that 2 hardware queues are unued ?

Comment: Cisco has evolved several versions of queuing models, depending on the traffic types and capabilities of the devices.  There is no one model. But requests for resources are off-topic here.

Comment: Thanks Ron. For example here are the Cat6800 hardware queues capabilities (https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/switches/catalyst-6800-series-switches/datasheet-c78-739155.html):   

Receive:
●  1p7q4t (default)
●  2p6q4t (configurable)

Transmit:
●  1p7q4t (default)
●  2p6q4t (configurable) .

The question was if CBWFQ define software queues, how these software queues are mapped to these hardware queues ? Or, do these hardware queues are only relevant if we use WRR or DWRR .